# Merging bitmap and a color in single bitmap

Tags: android

I need to merge a bitmap and a color value. how to do this in android. please post some method to implement this.i tried by using this.

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor));
Drawable bitmapOrg = Context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shade_brush).mutate();
bitmapOrg.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), colorValues[position].intValue()));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Modulation? Addition?

Comment: i need to blend a bitmap with a color value

Comment: Ok, and in what way does the results differ from what you expected? What's the value of `colorValues[position].intValue()` ?

Comment: i'm having some color hex values in colorValues[] ,i'm getting only the color when it displayed..i need that color to be applied over the bitmap

Comment: i have img.. what i exactly need, but i'm unable to post image here ..y ?

Comment: When else would you need the filter to be applied other than when you display the bitmap? Are you saying that you want to save the filtered bitmap to a file? It looks to me like your bitmap is a resource, so why not just include a bunch of pre-filtered bitmaps in your resources?

Comment: i load color values dynamically .so it is not fixed one.so i can't use  pre-filtered bitmaps.

Comment: These are images.i need result like this http://www.sendspace.com/file/pymely http://www.sendspace.com/file/l0vw89